# How can I exponentially scale the Y axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a matplotlib plot with an exponential(?) Y axis like the fake one I've mocked up below. For my data I want to spread the values out as they approach the max Y value. And I'd like to compress the values as Y gets close to zero.

All the normal 'log' examples do the opposite: they compress values as they get away from zero. Which is what 'log' does of course. How can I create an exponential(?) scaling instead?

[image: graph]

Comment: Exponential how? - What is the function that the y axis will be scaled to? Why would log-log axes be inadequate?

Comment: I'm not positive the exact function, but I would like a knob that allows me to have the Y values be smoothly compressed as they approach zero as above. I would say 10**Y but then not sure about Y between [0..1].  But with above values I care a lot about Y=10 vs. Y=9 and values in between.  But anything below Y=5 for example is pretty unimportant.  This doesn't seem like a crazy thing to want is it?

Comment: Not crazy, I've seen instruments with different scaling for different portions of the range.  It might take some work, the approach @Tommy suggested would work for scaling the values - then you have to figure out how to label the axis.  Did you search through the gallery and the ```Axes``` docs?

Answer (score 12):

From matplotlib 3.1 onwards you can define any custom scale easily via

```py
ax.set_yscale('function', functions=(forward, inverse))
```

Also see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/scales/scales.html

In this case, e.g.:

```py
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 40, 100)
y = np.linspace(1, 4, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

# Set y scale to exponential
ax.set_yscale('function', functions=(partial(np.power, 10.0), np.log10))
ax.set(xlim=(1,40), ylim=(1,4))
ax.set_yticks([1, 3, 3.5, 3.75, 4.0])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A short fix, the inverse of 10 ** x is np.log10(x), rather then np.log(x).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think its directly possible. But of course you can always try cheating. In my example I just write something else in the label:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 40, 100);
y = np.linspace(1, 4, 100);

# Actually plot the exponential values
plt.plot(x, np.e**y)
ax = plt.gca()

# Set x logaritmic
ax.set_xscale('log')

# Rewrite the y labels
y_labels = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 4)
ax.set_yticks(np.e**y_labels)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels)

plt.show()
```

Which results into:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not fully general because the locators are hard coded for my case. But this worked for me. I had to create a new scale called ExponentialScale used ma.power with a base of 1.1. Way too complicated for a seemingly simple thing:

```
class ExponentialScale(mscale.ScaleBase):
    name = 'expo'
    base = 1.1
    logbase = math.log(base)

def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
    mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self)
    self.thresh = None #thresh

def get_transform(self):
    return self.ExponentialTransform(self.thresh)

def set_default_locators_and_formatters(self, axis):
    # I could not get LogLocator to do what I wanted. I don't understand
    # the docs about "subs" and the source was not clear to me.
    # So I just spell out the lines I want:
    major = [1, 5, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 25, 28, 30] + range(31,60)
    axis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(major))

class ExponentialTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
    input_dims = 1
    output_dims = 1
    is_separable = True

    def __init__(self, thresh):
        mtransforms.Transform.__init__(self)
        self.thresh = thresh

    def transform_non_affine(self, a):
        res = ma.power(ExponentialScale.base, a)
        return res

    def inverted(self):
        return ExponentialScale.InvertedExponentialTransform(self.thresh)

class InvertedExponentialTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
    input_dims = 1
    output_dims = 1
    is_separable = True

    def __init__(self, thresh):
        mtransforms.Transform.__init__(self)
        self.thresh = thresh

    def transform_non_affine(self, a):
        denom = np.repeat(ExponentialScale.logbase, len(a))
        return np.log(a) / denom

    def inverted(self):
        return ExponentialScale.ExponentialTransform(self.thresh)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reference. The subs are the points you want to label along every [1, 10) range. For example, [1, 2, 5] labels [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, ...]. FYI you might also want to put in `set_default_locators_and_formatters` the line `axis.set_smart_bounds(True)`. I had an issue where ticks were getting drawn past the end of the spine without this line.

Answer (score 0):

**What would it mean to have exponential scaling?**

In log axis, a power relationship, `y=x**a`, will yield a straight line with slope `a`. This is because we plot `log(y) = log(x**a) = a log(x)`.

With a exponential axis, the relationship `y=log(a x)` should yield a straight line with slope `a`: `exp(y) = exp[log(a x)] = a x`.

**How to deal with this simply**

just take the exponent yourself and label the axis to indicate that this operation was done.

```
plt.plot(np.exp(your_x_data), np.exp(your_y_data))
plt.xlabel('exp(x)')
plt.xlabel('exp(y)')
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean X axis because in your mock figure, the X axis is exponential, not the Y axis.

You can do something like this:

```
...
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(Xs,Ys,color='blue',linewidth=2)
....
xlabs = [pow(10,i) for i in range(0,6)]
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabs)
ax.set_xticks(xlabs)
```

What I am doing here is manually creating a list of 6 Xs where each is represented by `10^i`, i.e., `10^1,10^2,...`. This will put X tick marks, and label them correctly, at `[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]`. If you need more labels, change the `6`.

Comment: No I mean Y axis.... X is 'log' here but Y is exponential. X had a huge range and nice labels so it's clear. Y is exponential it's just the labels/grids are bad. Notice the distance from 10.9 to 9.9 relative to 9.9 to 0.9. I want matplotlib to actually scale my data like 'log' does but exponentially. Not just have exponentially spaced labels.

Answer (score -1):

simply add this into your code for log scale:

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

But if you do want a exponential scale, this question answers it:
[link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395554/custom-axis-scales-reverse-logarithmic)

Comment: ah true, skim read the question. Added a link to how to do it

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your code:

```
plt.yscale('symlog')
```

Source: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html